# Vi Mode for redis-cli

Tags: command-line, redis, vi

I have `set editing-mode vi` in .inputrc, which affects consoles for Ruby, MySQL, etc. It doesn't work for Redis though and I'm wondering if there's any way to make it so (ideally on OSX and Linux).

(It's mentioned here too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @h2ero said redis-cli provides own line editing layer and it doesn't use `readline`.

Try to use [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap):

```
$ rlwrap -a -- redis-cli
```

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work alone, but then I installed repl (http://defunkt.io/repl/) and the combination *does* work, using `repl redis-cli`. Vim bindings for Redis unlocked! Can you please update your answer to mention repl too and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the `-a` flag  is for, but it caused an error on OSX (`on this system, the getopt() library function doesn't
grok optional arguments, so 'redis-cli' is taken as an argument to the -a option`).

Comment: It's strange - `repl` should be used only for noniteractive commands  (it wraps itself in `rlwrap` and creates simple command loop which executes `redis-cli` with every input line), but `redis-cli` without params should run in interactive mode... Anyway I have to use `-a` option on my version of rlwrap and redis (0.37 and 2.6.14) on my Arch Linux box. Could you give a try: `rlwrap -a -- redis-cli`?

Comment: I've updated answer to `$ rlwrap -a -- redis-cli` as it works on all versions of `getopt` library.

Comment: For completions not to be a garbled mess I also need to add `-t dumb`. `rlwrap -a -t dumb redis-cli` works great :)

Comment: NOTE about history file:  
`redis-cli` use ~/.rediscli_history, but `rlwrap` use /.redis-cli_history.   
if want them share history: `ln -s .rediscli_history ~/.redis-cli_history`

Comment: use rlwrap seems lose auto-complete

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded redis source  code and found redis cli it hadn't used readline library (readline/readline.h). so it can't use  key binding.

http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html